# Ubuntu 12.04, xbmc, opengl, intel motherboard

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, intel, mythtv, xbmc

I've got an HTPC that I built myself, with a Asus P5G41T-M Motherboard. It's got an on-board HDMI port, and I've been using that with no problems. I started out with Mythbuntu ( an older version ), and recently updated to 12.04.1 LTS without any issues.

I've been thinking about trying out XBMC for a while, and I decided to give it a go. Unfortunately, I seem to be running into quite a few issues.

I got XBMC installed from the repos without any issues, but when I try to run it from a console, a box pops up with the following:

> XBMC needs hardware accelerated OpenGL rendering.
> Install an appropriate graphics driver.
>
> Please consule XBMC Wiki for supported hardware http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Supported_hardware

In the console, it prints out the following:

```
X Error of failed request: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

When I run vainfo, I get this:

```
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.32 (libva 1.0.15)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver - 1.0.15
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
```

The file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i964_drv_video.so exists:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 628728 Mar 29  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
```

And in /var/log/Xorg.0.log the following error pops up:

```
GLX error: Can not get required symbols.
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've tried searching all over for how to fix this problem. I've done "apt-get --reinstall xserver-xorg" ( as well as a few other video driver packages ) a few times, and no change.

Any help in getting this issue sorted out would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to get my onboard `Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express` to work, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

This will remove any remnants of possible proprietary Nvidia driver stuff and install the necessary Intel drivers and the necessary OpenGL support.